# HBase Zookeeper connection error

Tags: docker, networking, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am running a Hbase inside a docker container. When it starts up using a docker-compose file, I am seeing the following error:

> WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxn: caught end of stream exception
>
> EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x16205128eac02db, likely client has closed socket
>
> at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
>
> at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       2018-03-08 12:59:45,737 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /172.18.0.2:45372 which had sessionid 0x16205128eac02db

And I am also seeing the following when i run a mapreduce to get data from Hbase:

```
Disconnecting client for session: 0x16205128eac00dc org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn.disconnect(ClientCnxn.java:1290) 
An exception was thrown while closing send thread for session 0x16205128eac00dc : Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x16205128eac00dc, likely server has closed socket org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1086)
```

Is there any way I can fix this? My zoo.cfg file looks like this:

```
clientPort=2181
clientPortAddress=hbase-docker
server.1=hbase-docker:2181
maxClientCnxns=200
```

Docker-compose file looks like this:

```
hbase-docker:
  hostname: "hbase-docker"
  container_name: "hbase-docker"
  build:
    dockerfile: "Dockerfile-5.6"
    context: "./hbase-docker/"
  volumes:
  - "./hbase-docker/data:/data"
  ports:
  - "2181:2181"
```

> HBase version in docker container is: **1.2.4**
>
> Zookeeper version: **3.4.6-1569965**
>
> Docker version: **17.12.1-ce, build 7390fc6**
>
> Docker Compose version: **1.16.1, build 6d1ac21**
>
> OS version: **Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (xenial)**

Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# HBase in Docker
#
# Version 0.3

# http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/builder/

FROM ubuntu:xenial

COPY *.sh /build/

ENV HBASE_VERSION 1.2.4

RUN mkdir -p /var/zookeeper && \
    /build/prepare-hbase.sh && \
    cd /opt/hbase && /build/build-hbase.sh \
    cd / && /build/cleanup-hbase.sh 

VOLUME /data

ADD ./hbase-site.xml /opt/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml

ADD ./zoo.cfg /opt/hbase/conf/zoo.cfg

ADD ./replace-hostname /opt/replace-hostname

ADD ./hbase-server /opt/hbase-server

# REST API
EXPOSE 8080
# REST Web UI at :8085/rest.jsp
EXPOSE 8085
# Thrift API
EXPOSE 9090
# Thrift Web UI at :9095/thrift.jsp
EXPOSE 9095
# HBase's Embedded zookeeper cluster
EXPOSE 2181
# HBase Master web UI at :16010/master-status;  ZK at :16010/zk.jsp
EXPOSE 16010

CMD ["/opt/hbase-server"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing [dataDir](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperStarted.html#sc_InstallingSingleMode) in zoo.cfg file.

`dataDir = /path/to/zookeeper/data`

Make sure the directory you specify 
already exists or you would require to add in [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) to create this directory and then rebuild image with different name.

Comment: After adding the following in zoo.cfg (dataDir=/var/zookeeper) and the following in Dockerfile (RUN mkdir -p /var/zookeeper), I am still seeing this issue. Any other ideas? @slashpai

Comment: Did you rebuild the image? Verify conf after container is up

Comment: Yep, I rebuild the image and also removed all existing docker images using (docker system prune -a -f) so that the new image will be used. I verified by going inside container and making sure changes took effect. But still same error. @slashpai

Comment: The port's section in docker compose is that of zookeeper not hbase.. Can you post contents in Dockerfile

Comment: I would suggest first run docker command to test it is working as expected and then create compose file for future use https://github.com/dajobe/hbase-docker/blob/master/README.md#run-hbase